# How to record access to virtual page of process in linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want to track the access count of pages by a application with swap enable.

Does modify `mark_page_accessed` to implement it is possible?
Or other solution which is more elegant and convenient?
If it can be done in user space that would be better, plz give me some tips.
Thanks!

I have googled but could not find a specific solution.
It would be great if you can give some tips.

Comment: AFAIK Linux does not track accesses to physical pages, it tracks accesses to virtual pages.

Comment: Actually I want to track the access count of pages by a application with swap enable, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/soft-dirty.html maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still get problems. I have read the doc and found that the soft-dirty bits can only track the write to page. Is there any bit in PTE can track both read and write to page (I found there is an access bit in PTE)? And how to decide the time window to clear the bit?

Comment: You can try using `perf` to track that specific function in a process.

Comment: I want to track the accurate read/write count of each page. Tracking specific function might not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smapling way works by clearing the pte bits constantly and Working Set Size (WSS) Tools (https://github.com/brendangregg/wss) is a good choice.